# ListBox SelectionChanged and Image Tap event Order

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, listbox

I Have an image within an ItemTemplate of ListBox, on the Tap event I execute an action.

on the SelectionChanged event of the ListBox I navigate to another Page when user does not tap on the image: my problem is the order of the these events: the selectionChanged event occurs before the tap event then the navigation occurs before the event Tap

how can I solve this problem? help please

In selectionChanged I test if it is not refresh (a boolean that I set to true when image Tap event trigged) I navigate to another page and if it is refresh I do not navigate

with a LongListSelector it works well because tap events is trigged first but not with ListBox (ReorderListBox exactly).

My datatemplate contains others controls:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" >
        <Grid Height="150" Width="408" Background="White" Margin="0,0,0,14">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu  >
                <toolkit:ContextMenu Height="150" Background="#26AA99" BorderBrush="Transparent"  Unloaded="ContextMenu_Unloaded"  >
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.PinToStart, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"   Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="26" Click="MIPinSchedule_Click"   />
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Delete, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"    Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="26" Click="MIDeleteSchedule_Click"   />
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="{Binding LineColor}" Height="14" Width="408"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0" Foreground="#00418D" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="26"/>

        <Grid   >
            <!--Les deux prochais passages-->
            <phone:LongListSelector 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding NextStopCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            LayoutMode="List"                                          
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate2}" />
            <!--Boutton refresh qui s'affiche au bout de 20 secondes-->
            <Image  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   Height="48" Width="48" 
                           Source="/Assets/Refresh.png" Tap="Refresh_Tap" 
                           Visibility="{Binding  ElementName=reorderListBox, Path=DataContext.IsOutOfDate,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


private void reorderListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rlb = sender as ReorderListBox.ReorderListBox;
        if (rlb.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        if (!viewModel._isRefresh)
        {
            var selectedItem = rlb.SelectedItem as MyObject;

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(MyUri, UriKind.Relative));

        }

        _isRefresh = false;
        rlb.SelectedItem = null;
    }

 private void Refresh_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
       //Do action
        _isRefresh = true;
    }
```

Comment: what are you doing on selection changed? and does your listbox contains only an image in the datatemplate or there are other UI elements as well?.. Please share with your xaml

Comment: See Edit please @Aman Khandelwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you discard the `SelectionChanged` event completely and instead add a `Tap` event on the `Grid` in your `DataTemplate`.